# Wrong number in binary search

Tags: python, binary-search

I am making this binary search program in Python and I have a very long list (1000 numbers long).

You are supposed to write in a number yourself, and the program should give you the index of where that number is placed in the list (provided the number you write in is in the list). However, this the index given rarely is the exact actual index. Say, the actual index of a number is 300, the program will maybe say 301, or 302. It is very close, but not perfect. Sometimes though, it does give the right answer. I would like it to give the exact correct answer, but I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
print ('BINARY SEARCH PROGRAMME\n')
data = [3079, 1006, 1965, 3275, 1466, 3498, 3606, 8140, 2854, 6241, 7216, 2973, 641, 9911, 7346, 5211, 4851, 4023, 9335, 6645, 7951, 1034, 581, 1585, 5519, 8386, 204, 3700, 1737, 8597, 4922, 7094, 4329, 8766, 1092, 1799, 1151, 8316, 4267, 2368, 9505, 2829, 1986, 3527, 8817, 1013, 6209, 7749, 8152, 3887, 1361, 702, 1888, 6807, 9101, 523, 1862, 46, 5094, 4799, 625, 946, 5684, 5832, 1650, 9902, 2727, 4896, 616, 166, 8065, 5033, 9533, 1833, 220, 9397, 6388, 9185, 4247, 3676, 7673, 2437, 5206, 2130, 4553, 2492, 2719, 6212, 5541, 7550, 4685, 4157, 2336, 5759, 5896, 1327, 4004, 4573, 3213, 9708, 1677, 9583, 8436, 4220, 3229, 1261, 1377, 8365, 2613, 407, 2115, 6429, 9410, 1029, 2224, 6753, 4099, 5966, 9341, 5764, 4381, 6461, 6834, 5089, 6518, 2402, 5685, 7705, 5188, 713, 7147, 6068, 3020, 5723, 4972, 5052, 7133, 8567, 7023, 8086, 9068, 1088, 9025, 7471, 4852, 2624, 7067, 3847, 9886, 8565, 1727, 79, 8563, 376, 9949, 2487, 2155, 9557, 6811, 9175, 9862, 998, 4009, 93, 6923, 4405, 3831, 3780, 6708, 1353, 144, 8801, 6855, 3826, 5253, 2582, 1925, 7419, 5580, 3956, 2320, 7855, 7046, 9992, 4184, 6648, 9706, 3002, 9395, 4265, 122, 8642, 3182, 3106, 2581, 8537, 6644, 1682, 7000, 858, 1686, 1518, 4461, 4728, 6195, 3391, 1929, 9055, 3814, 9391, 2527, 7888, 1464, 9455, 1516, 4464, 9784, 119, 16, 8145, 9683, 3530, 9457, 9310, 8551, 9214, 4501, 205, 9173, 8842, 9488, 4692, 993, 5452, 1807, 9405, 3272, 5295, 2984, 8835, 3534, 6436, 7429, 9729, 8975, 7513, 2453, 6935, 7481, 562, 69, 1169, 2752, 1280, 4829, 6147, 3380, 8296, 6546, 8083, 9585, 8494, 6915, 3320, 5439, 3536, 5309, 8652, 5747, 7073, 9624, 2946, 8055, 5261, 3083, 505, 639, 2859, 3582, 1407, 4027, 4048, 8329, 5454, 8805, 4079, 3192, 4978, 1298, 4873, 697, 3270, 2169, 2966, 1446, 5704, 3144, 9919, 9887, 7336, 2703, 8306, 2263, 5683, 4604, 5871, 6629, 8992, 3031, 4592, 6960, 7192, 1844, 8916, 8910, 7162, 1250, 4043, 7624, 6961, 1695, 2386, 1086, 7790, 3364, 8543, 8013, 2980, 4342, 8500, 453, 5320, 6409, 2923, 1531, 4505, 4089, 7387, 6440, 8513, 8586, 9131, 1093, 2611, 2804, 7417, 4678, 8924, 8811, 2630, 36, 7957, 7247, 2554, 3052, 8584, 4969, 7557, 9030, 2890, 9299, 7128, 1016, 9978, 3131, 96, 295, 3446, 1571, 2067, 604, 5120, 2644, 693, 6377, 8815, 2473, 2722, 1530, 4299, 3136, 872, 5419, 4654, 5283, 5506, 3715, 1376, 2682, 4107, 4493, 9570, 8898, 3611, 800, 4652, 6895, 6730, 2477, 5802, 8596, 4439, 3061, 2658, 5254, 3940, 194, 5225, 3764, 7181, 8707, 8040, 7433, 3018, 123, 9087, 9019, 8189, 1837, 4200, 4123, 9456, 2465, 6562, 7352, 147, 8706, 9425, 1266, 4971, 8718, 3796, 8876, 6988, 3709, 5625, 3169, 5480, 6721, 274, 2036, 8236, 208, 7621, 805, 2903, 8663, 9986, 3404, 9463, 8103, 5047, 9355, 6120, 7207, 2112, 310, 4747, 3366, 6530, 9347, 7246, 4574, 912, 1555, 4755, 9674, 875, 9880, 4297, 4537, 2710, 8641, 1814, 535, 1870, 6033, 4327, 5011, 8549, 6199, 6676, 9913, 6483, 3470, 3096, 7152, 8338, 346, 9421, 8570, 8068, 9331, 7827, 7622, 472, 4514, 2605, 9647, 7864, 7021, 4797, 1144, 7324, 5835, 4435, 8542, 948, 9573, 7602, 52, 7805, 6322, 371, 3426, 3763, 1715, 2236, 1279, 9868, 9191, 7150, 4379, 4447, 4038, 667, 1265, 9630, 9814, 9592, 556, 8710, 6861, 5864, 114, 127, 4460, 4124, 1639, 2716, 4586, 8071, 109, 1766, 8121, 4120, 7955, 828, 14, 7154, 618, 9636, 9313, 8408, 4418, 1900, 3001, 9820, 811, 9386, 8941, 3681, 2442, 8752, 6477, 331, 597, 5087, 2475, 8951, 3040, 3607, 4305, 7730, 9953, 2991, 6795, 1454, 8171, 4494, 8120, 6554, 9521, 8487, 4240, 1064, 822, 5823, 5756, 5371, 3058, 7416, 788, 7498, 4352, 4142, 5719, 4091, 3316, 4578, 1708, 6888, 3977, 4820, 790, 9108, 430, 6924, 6152, 4409, 8383, 6734, 3601, 6316, 8643, 8903, 6607, 3679, 2921, 1792, 8456, 6913, 1297, 1091, 2083, 3203, 3033, 6159, 3839, 6934, 4688, 1758, 5082, 6251, 7856, 8717, 1315, 2329, 1187, 9631, 2333, 4041, 3840, 2429, 5730, 9152, 2614, 8461, 8544, 1176, 8759, 9598, 2041, 4377, 973, 3744, 4292, 8922, 5838, 6869, 3004, 2513, 1767, 3414, 9715, 9718, 8019, 5282, 9889, 3438, 975, 1081, 1780, 7909, 7376, 7605, 8708, 9723, 1457, 3666, 4594, 5727, 9294, 6487, 2508, 3600, 9350, 8751, 9121, 5927, 8203, 8250, 3591, 1917, 4513, 9287, 1041, 9342, 7370, 3402, 6871, 4551, 1632, 2413, 6183, 2291, 4176, 7006, 9771, 9568, 5760, 6657, 4239, 6198, 2610, 9207, 8692, 7089, 7866, 4236, 5713, 9385, 7001, 43, 1343, 7958, 2608, 9377, 5075, 3990, 5124, 9728, 8519, 4623, 5613, 7981, 1832, 275, 4375, 1044, 8573, 9782, 738, 421, 2999, 7511, 3888, 1337, 390, 1987, 8735, 2953, 4237, 5234, 9070, 1693, 7769, 2085, 8698, 762, 7563, 7443, 7271, 3989, 7524, 6083, 5398, 2575, 5367, 5686, 870, 7331, 5659, 3363, 3539, 9061, 7802, 9910, 7520, 1707, 2532, 4479, 5517, 7975, 6177, 3116, 653, 9677, 7721, 9969, 6772, 507, 1763, 168, 1924, 6364, 9877, 9485, 2250, 1497, 1395, 5158, 7233, 229, 4119, 8190, 9836, 9654, 3580, 9801, 7668, 2846, 8636, 6397, 3560, 2460, 8509, 6371, 4144, 8850, 5878, 5266, 1211, 9678, 2371, 1123, 8015, 1161, 3242, 2518, 5718, 4643, 314, 3784, 4249, 8554, 9102, 9524, 4795, 2167, 5346, 5644, 5954, 7312, 6770, 9688, 4425, 664, 7364, 5614, 512, 7634, 8812, 367, 3957, 9498, 2463, 6825, 2886, 8610, 5255, 8345, 5850, 4231, 5748, 6248, 6787, 345, 9713, 5923, 6843, 318, 8491, 9841, 9792, 1009, 9603, 2956, 106, 5937, 3650, 4842, 9756, 1995, 1940, 2227, 9619, 7013, 2542, 223, 3345, 4216, 6021, 3465, 3868, 7731, 5851, 7782, 6973, 3503, 4859, 7390, 207, 1208, 3012, 5006, 5505, 2797, 9558, 1109, 1662, 9555, 2996, 5744, 8734, 5005, 2838, 8555, 7132, 5200, 1906, 1757, 9096, 9639, 4884, 3491, 8433, 9591, 7385, 746, 1335, 6941, 5160, 3341, 4893, 4344, 2537, 2212, 4017, 6433, 1441, 7085, 1652, 8133, 3084, 9812, 9218, 3589, 8748, 2747, 4325, 3720, 228, 3238, 6299, 9821, 6565, 3646, 5086, 1477, 3859, 9003, 5642, 9086, 9774, 8535, 736, 8508, 8488, 7035, 9398, 8932, 6175, 8309, 5769, 7191, 22, 6469, 290, 4244, 4078, 8072, 214, 2835, 6737, 4691, 4726, 1291, 1242, 9172, 1559, 1236, 7899, 4882, 1195, 5576, 504, 6652, 3746]
data = sorted(data)

indl = 0
roun = 0

inp = int(input('Enter number to search:\n'))

if inp in data:
    while len(data) > 1:
        if len(data) % 2 == 0:
            half = len(data) / 2
        elif len(data) % 2 == 1:
            half = int(round(float(len(data) / 2)))

        half = int(half)
        
        if inp < data[half]:
            data = data[:half]
        elif len(data) < 3 and inp == data[half]:
            indl = indl + half
            break
    
        else:
            while len(data) > half:
                data.remove(data[0])
            indl = indl + int(len(data))
else:
    print ('\nNumber not found\n')

print ('The given number is on index number:\n', indl)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this code? What was stopping you from making your program give the correct output? Did you try to debug the program? What did you find?

Comment: Why do you use `float` and `round`? This might have something to do with the results only being *almost* correct. Why not use *exact* calculations?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I use {float} and {round} because that will give the right answer. When dividing, say 125 and 2, you will get 61.5. I need an integer, therefore I use {round} to make it an integer. To use {round}, it has to be used on a {float}, therefore, just to be sure, I convert the number to a float, temporarily, before converting it to an integer again.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't always give the right answer, though. The question is *which* integer do you need? Do you need 61 or 62 in your example?

Comment: By the way: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have tried debugging it, but I don't see the issue. Also, I am doing it at school, with a bunch of others around me making a lot of noise, making the debugging process a bit difficult. Hoped somebody would find the issue.

Comment: In my example, I would like to have 62, and that's what I get in my programme. Maybe this is part of the issue. I am not sure. I think 62, because the actual answer is 61.5, but I need whole objects, not half ones, obviously. Therefore I just include one more to be sure. That's why I pick 62 instead of 61, but maybe I am thinking the wrong way.

Comment: If there are classmates around, that's perfect. Then you can apply one of the techniques explained in the article I've linked, where you explain to someone else how your code is supposed to work. Likely in the process you, or the other person, will spot a mistake.

Comment: @mkrieger1 haha, that is not how I meant. I am 15, and my classmates are playing Among Us. They have no experience with Python whatsoever, so there is no help asking them.

Comment: Here is what `round(x / 2)` gives for different values of `x` between 122 and 130: `122 → 61; 123 → 62; 124 → 62; 125 → 62; 126 → 63; 127 → 64; 128 → 64; 129 → 64; 130 → 65`. I would focus on checking if this is always the expected value.